# How to do hibernate manual join?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Model class, if i put annotation

```
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(....
 public AnotherModel getAnotherModel(){

 }
```

the above will always eagerly fetch classA join with AnotherModel class.  If i only want to return classA without AnotherModel class. how should i put the annotation ?  Because only certain cases only that i need join classA with AnotherModel. I want to do this in DAO-Criteria rather than map inside Model.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the association to be lazily fetched, if it is not optional, i.e. may not be null.

Have a look here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one

Comment: even if i put (fetch=lazyloading) ,    even though, the query will to join with anotherModel class .  it will just try to lazy load it as a second new sql query. i do not want that. i only need to join with anothermodel when i put that in criteria-query-dao

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ManyToOne` it's the standard for foreign key mappings.